# how to include js file in an html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement a virtual keyboard in my project. I never included that before so i referred to a link and i tried that as below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vkboards.js"></script>

    <script>

    // Minimal callback function:
    function keyb_callback(char)
    {
        // bind vkeyboard to the <TEXTAREA>

        // with id="textfield":
        var text =
            document.getElementById("textfield"), val = text.value;

        switch(ch)
        {
            case "BackSpace":
            var min=(val.charCodeAt(val.length - 1) == 10) ? 2 : 1;
            text.value = val.substr(0, val.length - min);
            break;

           case "Enter":
               text.value += "\n";
               break;

           default:
               text.value += ch;
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
```

in style:

```
#keyboard
{
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#f2f3f1;
    margin:1px auto;
    border-radius:25px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px grey;
}
```

in body:

```
<body onload="new Vkeyboard("keyboard", keyb_callback);">
    <TEXTAREA id="textfield" rows="1" cols="25"></TEXTAREA>
    <div id="keyboard"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried this,searched net but nothing made it work. Please go through my code and help me to correct it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, _you_ go through _your_ code and learn how to debug things. You should be checking your error console for errors and adding `console.log`s to check things are what they're supposed to be. If you _still_ can't solve the problem, ask a question here. Otherwise as it currently stands you're just being lazy

Comment: I don't understand the correlation between the title of your question and the body. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I am writing code in notepad. @Bojangles. well, thanks for ur kind advice.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing the quotes around keyboard to single quotes like this.

```
<body onload="new Vkeyboard('keyboard', keyb_callback);">
```

Comment: The vkboards.js that you included, what is the link to it's source? What exactly is the behaviour that you're seeing? Is the keyboard just not showing up? Are there any errors in the js console?

Comment: Also you seem to have an extra </div> just floating around in there.

Comment: the keyb is not showing up. also m coding in notepad so can't have any errors.

Comment: Errors on the console are usually displayed in the browser. What browser are you looking at your page in? Both in firefox and in chrome I know you can right click on your webpage and select "Inspect Element". Other browsers probably have something similar. You then click on console and reload the page. That should let you know if there are any errors. There are also browser addons you can use such as Firebug for Firefox that will display the console (and other things)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with quotes in your `body` tag.  You are opening and closing string a lot which is making your js inoperable.  Change your `body` tag to:

```
<body onload="new Vkeyboard('keyboard', keyb_callback);">
```

Comment: Check your path for including vkboards.js

Comment: its in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Where is your function VKeyboard() ?

You are creating an object new Vkeyboard(  in your body tag.  But you have no script for that. I am guessing your are missing a javascript file?

did you lift this code off a site or is it something you have?

Above the  tag, there should be a reference to a javascript file

Your code is incomplete.

Comment: A script was added after I posted this...

Comment: I also suggest, in Firefox, you click on your included javascript file and see if it actually exists.. Furthermore, since you obviously didn't write this, you should go to the developer's site.

Comment: As i mentioned,i tried it for first time also i donno much about JScript. I searched the net thoroughly but can't find any related tutorial. So, i thought may be this site could help. But here also everybody is voting me down only..